# Multiple Cursors for Sikuli Automation

Tags: automation, sikuli

Is there an already existing program which creates a dummy cursor for Sikuli to use whilst the user maintains control of the Mouse cursor? I am looking for ways to make debugging code less arduous when working with Sikuli. Any tips in that regard are also welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Sikuli does not mock a mouse cursor but works with mouse and keyboard through Java Robot library to generate native system input events. Some doco on that can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).